# Login with google api in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to manage the api when user deny the access in authorization popup screen. we do not have option to set de-authorization url like facebook and linkedin.

Answer (score 0):

Do a test on login to check if connection d to the social sites are active. Assuming you have stored the access tokens

Answer (score 0):

Try use: https://github.com/moemoe89/google-login-ci3

library Googleplus.php has the features you are looking for

Comment: still not done when i click deny following error occur.

Comment: message: error calling get https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo: (401) invalid credentials while user deny